# To show that $d_g (p, q) >0$ when $p\neq q$ on $(M, g)$

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold. It is easy to show that every two points is joined by an admissible (i.e. piecewise smooth regular) curve. Define

$$\tag{1} d_g (p, q) = \inf \left\{ L(\gamma):= \int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|_g dt:  \gamma : [a, b] \to M \text{ admissible }, \gamma(a) = p, \gamma(b) = q\right\}$$

It is well known and proved in different textbooks that $d_g$ defines a metric on $M$. The only part that needs a proof is
$$\tag{2} d_g(p, q) >0 \text{ whenever }p\neq q$$
and the proof goes like this:

> Pick a coordinates neighborhood $U$ or $p$ disjoint from $q$, so that $U \cong B_\epsilon(0)$, the Euclidean ball of radius $\epsilon$, $p$ is sent to $0$, and that on $U$, $g$ is uniform equivalent to the Euclidean metric $g_0$. Let $\gamma$ be any admissible curve joining $p$ to $q$. Let $t_0 \in [a, b]$ be the first time the curve $\gamma$ leaves $U$. Then $\gamma(t_0)$ lies in the boundary of $U$, identified as $\partial B_\epsilon (0)$. Thus
> $$ L_g(\gamma|_{[a, t_0]}) \ge c L_{g_0} (\gamma|_{[a, t_0]}) \ge c\epsilon >0.$$

The part that I am confused is why $\gamma (t_0)$ lies in the part identified as $\partial B_\epsilon (0)$. How do I prove it rigorously?

What I find confusing is that the above proof does not use the Hausdorff condition. Without the Hausdorff condition, $d_g$ defined in (1) does not satisfy (2): Think of $M$ as the line with two origins and let $g$ be the Euclidean metric defined on $M$. Then one can easily find piecewise smooth curves of arbitrary small length connecting the two origins.

Comment: I think it's simply incorrect that $\partial U$ is identified with $\partial B_{\varepsilon}(0)$. This can be observed in your example of the line with two origins too (any interval containing one origin has three boundary points: the usual endpoints, which get identified with the endpoints of the interval in the chart, and the other origin). To get such a thing, you'd have to first take a larger coordinate neighborhood and then choose $U$ to correspond to the interior of a compact ball - the argument that this works then requires that compact => closed in a Hausdorff space.

Comment: You use the Hausdorff condition when you find $U$ such that $q$ does not lie in $U$, but $p$ does. For $\gamma(t_0)$, you can reason by contradiction : if $\gamma(t_0)$ lies inside $U$, then for small $\delta$, $\gamma(t)$ also lies in $U$ when $t_0 \leq t \leq t_0 + \delta$, which contradicts the definition of $t_0$. (or similarly if $\gamma(t_0)$ is outside $U$ and not on the boundary)

Comment: "$q$ does not lie in $U$ but $p$ does" That is just the $T_1$ condition, you haven't used the Hausdorff condition yet (and the line with two origins is $T_1$). Also, I have no problem showing that $\gamma (t_0) \notin U$, but why it's on $\partial B_\epsilon (0)$.  @Rondoudou

Comment: The point is that you have disjoint geodesic balls, one centered at $p$ and one centered at $q$. So any curve joining $p$ to $q$ has to leave one ball and enter the other.

Comment: @Thorgott I think you nailed it.